# Dispose issue, should I ignore Visual Studio warning?

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

I created an user control that inherits from a Panel.
I have a bunch of pens  brushes and VS warns me (CA2213: Disposable fields should be disposed)

I've this method :

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        myPen?.Dispose();
        myBrush?.Dispose();
        // etc...
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thank you for your answers !

Edit :

I suppressed the warning by overriding Dispose() in the my user-control and free all IDisposable fields there.

```
protected new void Dispose() 
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
       myPen?.Dispose();
       // etc..
       disposed = true;
    }

    base.Dispose(disposed);
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing thing correctly !

Edit #2 :

I can accept the answer, but was the first sample of code correct ?

Comment: Why would `components` be null and why is it a preclusion against disposing other fields?

Comment: Because the class is partial and the code has been generated, just added disposed call to the drawing stuff.

Comment: so , remove `(components != null)` and change `components.Dispose();` to `components?.Dispose();`

Comment: Same result, but I figured out how to remove the warning. I edited my post. Any constructive comment is welcome :)

Comment: Your new code *hides* the Dispose method rather than overriding it.  It will never be called.

Comment: Yes, I saw that article before posting but I was wondering how to dispose properly resources that have to be disposed while inheriting from a Panel.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (disposing && (components != null))
```

It might be perfectly sensible from other knowledge of how the class works that `components` being null means that no other disposal is required, but the analysis that gives the warning won't catch that.

```
protected new void Dispose()
```

This is useless because it won't be called upon disposing.

I would likely go for:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        myPen?.Dispose();
        myBrush?.Dispose();
        // etc...
        components?.Dispose();
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Though note that `?.` while a very good idea can sometimes also give a false warning. OTOH if you **do** know that `components == null` means no disposal is needed, then your initial code is fine, just disable the warning.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. And yes I removed that part already since I only had a container for a Timer, I used a  System.Timers.Timer instead and used that methods. Solved, thank you very much !